# Do you need c# to use wcf-soap?

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

Are you required to use a .net service to send and receive data using the WCF-SOAP framework/protocol?

I have an application using HTTP POST currently, but need to switch it over to use WCF and soap and am wondering if there is some way I can still use the code we have but change the data that we're sending. Or do I need to start from scratch in C#?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you don't need to use .net to send and receive data to a WCF service. You can still continue to use HTTP post. Here is an [overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd547388) of it.

Comment: I agree, REST via WCF is the way to go. I'd use JSON instead of SOAP for a binding.